# Add space character to the end of a particular line

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, batch-rename

I want to write a vbscript or batch file to run over almost a hundred files (in the same directory) and do the following:

For each line that starts with the string `"component "` (there is a space after component)
I want to add at the end of that line a space. Other lines won't be affected.

**For example:**

```
this is line one
component this is line two
this is line three
```

**will change to:**

```
this is line one
component this is line two (<=space)
this is line three
```

*(There is only one space after the word "two".)*

Comment: what have you tried so far? Are you using FileScriptingObject to read through each line? If so, it should be an easy InStr to find the component and then write the file back out with a space at the end of the line.  Can you post your code so we can look at it?

Comment: @Andrew `Scripting.FileSystemObject` is what you meant I presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in (file.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="component" (
echo %%a %%b >>temp.txt
) else (
echo %%a %%b>>temp.txt
)
)
del file.txt /f /s /q
ren temp.txt file.txt
```

Comment: works fine only without the space in the DELIMS command (delims=")

Comment: @terminetorx No worries, I missed the delims bit, glad it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

Set "File=Test.txt"
Set "Word=Component"

FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=* Delims=" %%# IN ("%FILE%") DO (
    Echo "%%#"| FINDSTR /I "^\"%WORD%.*\"" >NUL && (
        Echo %%# >>".\Output.txt"
    ) || (
        Echo %%#>>".\Output.txt"
    )
)

Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript you could do that with a regular expression:

```
in  = "input.txt"
out = "output.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

text = fso.OpenTextFile(in).ReadAll
text = Replace(text, vbCrLf, vbLf)         ' remove CR b/c it interferes with
                                           ' multiline matches

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern   = "^(component .*)$"
re.MultiLine = True
re.Global    = True

text = re.Replace(text, "$1 ")
text = Replace(text, vbLf, vbCrLf)         ' restore CRLF

fso.OpenTextFile(out, 2, True).Write(text)

fso.DeleteFile in
fso.MoveFile out, in
```